# Add text to my icons in my icon bar (HTML)

Tags: html, css

Hi I have some code for a icon bar below:

```
<body onload=startTime()>
<div id=txt></div>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"name=viewport>
<link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet>
<style>body{margin:0}.icon-bar{width:100%;background-color:#555;overflow:auto}.icon-bar a{float:left;width:20%;text-align:center;padding:12px 0;transition:all .3s ease;color:#fff;font-size:36px}.icon-bar a:hover{background-color:#000}.active{background-color:#4caf50!important}</style>
<body>
<div class=icon-bar>
<a href=Subpages/PC/pc.html><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
<a href=Subpages/Laptops/laptops.html><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i></a>
<a href=Subpages/Software/software.html><i class="fa fa-windows"></i></a>
<a href=Subpages/CoolStuff/coolstuff.html><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></a>
<a href=Subpages/About/About.html><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i></a>
</div>
```

It looks like this:
[image: Icon Bar]

I want some text below the icons to show my visitors what the icon means. I tried doing some text after the fa fa-***** but it keeps some text on the side. I went onto w3schools but they didn't have any text examples. I'm not sure if this is possible because this is a icon bar, not a text bar but maybe there is a way. If you know a way can you please reply.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
<body onload="startTime()">
        <div id="txt"></div>
        <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>body{margin:0}.icon-bar{width:100%;background-color:#555;overflow:auto}.icon-bar a{float:left;width:20%;text-align:center;padding:12px 0;transition:all .3s ease;color:#fff;font-size:36px}.icon-bar a:hover{background-color:#000}.active{background-color:#4caf50!important}</style>
        <div class="icon-bar">
          <a href="Subpages/PC/pc.html">
            <i class="fa fa-desktop"><p style="font-size:20px;">text1</p></i>
          </a>
          <a href="Subpages/Laptops/laptops.html">
            <i class="fa fa-laptop"><p style="font-size:20px;">text2</p></i>
          </a>
          <a href="Subpages/Software/software.html">
            <i class="fa fa-windows"><p style="font-size:20px;">text3</p></i>
          </a>
          <a href="Subpages/CoolStuff/coolstuff.html">
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o"><p style="font-size:20px;">text4</p></i>
          </a>
          <a href="Subpages/About/About.html">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"><p style="font-size:20px;">text5</p></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `span` tag to add text

```css
body{margin:0}.icon-bar{width:100%;background-color:#555;overflow:auto}.icon-bar a{float:left;width:20%;text-align:center;padding:12px 0;transition:all .3s ease;color:#fff;font-size:36px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px;}.icon-bar a:hover{background-color:#000}.active{background-color:#4caf50!important}
.icon-bar a span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body onload=startTime()>
<div id=txt></div>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"name=viewport>
<link href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet>

<div class=icon-bar>
<a href=Subpages/PC/pc.html><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><span>link</span></a>
<a href=Subpages/Laptops/laptops.html><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i><span>link</span></a>
<a href=Subpages/Software/software.html><i class="fa fa-windows"></i><span>link</span></a>
<a href=Subpages/CoolStuff/coolstuff.html><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i><span>link</span></a>
<a href=Subpages/About/About.html><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i><span>link</span></a>
</div>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hky4p4dh/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)